# Calling multiple images from poperty inside of property

Tags: reactjs

i am new to react and coding so sorry for my lack of technical language.

I am creating a product page for my website and i have a property list (i think that this is how it is called) and inside of a property i have another property with an images source directory.

```
const data = {
products:[
{
    _id:'1',
    name: 'Click Bar 2021',
    category: 'Bary',
    image:'/obrazy/clickbar.png',
    price:3300, 
    description:'...',
    img_name:'clickbar',
    img:[
        {
            src:'/obrazy/clickbar/1.png',
        },
        {
            src:'/obrazy/clickbar/2.png',
        },
    ]
},
```

I am trying to display images from src but nothing happens.

```
import React from 'react'
import data from '../data';

function ProductPage(props) {
const product = data.products.find((x) => x._id === props.match.params.id);
if(!product){
    return <div> Product not found</div>;
}
return(
    <div className="pp">
    <div className="row">
        <div className="pp-col1">
        <div className="pp-container">
            
            <img className = "pp-img"src={product.image}/>
            <h1>{product.name.toUpperCase(product.name)}</h1>
            <div className="small-imgs"> <img src={product.img.src} width="100px"/></div>
            {console.log(product.img.src)}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="pp-col2">
        <div className="pp-container">
        <a>{product.description}</a>
    </div>
    </div>
       
    </div>
    </div>
);
}
export default ProductPage;
```

There is probably a way to do it but i am really struggling with it and i did not find any solutions online.

Comment: You want show all images or only the first image

Answer (score 0):

the type of `img` is `array` so you should loop through this to get what you want.

Comment: thank you for your reply, unfortunately i do not understand. I am a total noob and also english is not my first language so i do not understand the terminology. Could you explain it a bit more for me please?